# Does Cloudant support TLS1.2 connections?

Tags: cloudant

I'm looking to make TLSv1.2 connections to Cloudant server. From the cloudant java client can we make TLSv1.2 connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your JVM support making such connections, it can make TLSv1.2 connections to cloudant.